# Usage of "any more than"

Tags: adverbs, multiple-negation

I came across this sentence:

> Kids don't like to be patronized, any more than adults **do**.

and wondered if I can also say it this way, and still convey the same meaning, (that none of them likes to be patronized):

> Kids don't like to be patronized, any more than adults **don't**.

Because the full sentence, before omitting the predictably repeated text, is:

> Kids don't like to be patronized, any more than adults **don't** like to be patronized

Comment: The phrase 'any more' followed by 'than' as used here is two words. The single word 'anymore' means 'any longer', e.g. _I don't eat meat anymore_,

Comment: The answer to your question is 'no'. You could say _Kids don't like to be patronized just as adults don't._

Comment: Think of it this way: which one makes sense?  *I like this as much as you do* OR *I like this as much as you don't*?  It's the same logic here.

Comment: @stangdon: I can't see there''s any particular "logic" to the idiomatically established form here. Both versions are "short for" *...any more than adults **don't like to be patronized*** - it's just that one version "deletes" all the "predictably repeated" text *including* negating (contracted) ***not***, but the other version doesn't start the deletion until ***like***. Most of the time this is a non-issue, though, because we'd usually start that deletion right from the word ***do***.

Comment: BM of Spadana - I'm not sure why this question attracted downvotes (imho that ***any more / anymore*** distinction is something *very* weird that primarily applies to AnE, not "my" BrE - it doesn't justify taking against the actual *question*). I can't answer your question myself, but you *might* find something useful in [Any more/any less than](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530287/any-more-any-less-than) as asked on our sister site ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you , exactly it's how I was thinking that this sentence is " ...any more than adults don't like to be patronized." and then when I omit the predictably repeated text, logically and grammatically it should be correct to say "Kids don't like to be patronized any more than adults don't."

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Think of it as "I am not any taller than you..."  What would you put there? *Are* or *aren't*?  Your rephrasing "...any more than adults *don't like to be patronized*" sounds flatly wrong to me; *do* in the original sentence is standing in for "like to be patronized", just like you would say "as tall as you *are*", not "as tall as you *aren't.*"

Comment: @stangdon: I completely agree that *...any more than adults don't [like to be patronized]* sounds flatly wrong. I'm just not convinced *logic* is a key factor here, so I'm not sure it necessarily helps BM of Spadana to be told that the idiomatically well-established version "makes sense". My advice is *Don't boil your brains trying to identify the "logical justification" for the "correct" version. It's an **idiom**, where you just have to commit what native speakers say to memory*.